# Saving RDD to file results in _temporary path for parts

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark, rdd

I have data in Spark which I want to save to S3. The recommended method is to save is using the `saveAsTextFile` method on the SparkContext, which is successful. I expect that the data will be saved as 'parts'.

My problem is that when I go to S3 to look at my data it has been saved in a folder name `_temporary`, with a subfolder `0` and then each part or task saved in its own folder.

For example,

```
data.saveAsTextFile("s3:/kirk/data");
```

results in file likes

```
s3://kirk/data/_SUCCESS
s3://kirk/data/_temporary/0/_temporary_$folder$
s3://kirk/data/_temporary/0/task_201411291454_0001_m_00000_$folder$
s3://kirk/data/_temporary/0/task_201411291454_0001_m_00000/part-00000
s3://kirk/data/_temporary/0/task_201411291454_0001_m_00001_$folder$
s3://kirk/data/_temporary/0/task_201411291454_0001_m_00001/part-00001
```

and so on. I would *expect* and have seen something like

```
s3://kirk/data/_SUCCESS
s3://kirk/data/part-00000
s3://kirk/data/part-00001
```

Is this a configuration setting, or do I need to 'commit' the save to resolve the temporary files?

Comment: I got the same problem, it only happens to large number of partitions

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with spark streaming, that was because my Sparkmaster was set up with `conf.setMaster("local")` instead of `conf.SetMaster("local[*]")`
Without the `[*]`,  spark can't execute `saveastextfile` during the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Try using coalesce() to reduce the rdd to 1 partition before you export.
Good luck!